# Mongoid and Cancan role inheritance / Many roles per User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mongoid, cancan

I am playing around with Mongoid (NoMySQL Database), DEVISE and CANACN

I have read the manual (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization),
but I dont wanna use the "roleMask"-calculation. I wanna use an Array (or Hash) -field instead, containing the roles of a user.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, :type => String, :null => false
  field :roles, :type => Array, default: -> { ['User'] if new_record?}
```

Is this possible in any way? And when yes, how? :-)

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancan doesn't really care how your roles work - your ability file is pure ruby so the logic is entirely up to you. For example you might have this in your ability:

```
can :manage, Product
```

If you want to restrict this to users whose roles array contains a certain value then you could do

```
if user.roles.include?('Admin')
  can :manage, Product
end
```

Since your ability is just a ruby class you can do pretty much anything that you can express in ruby.

There are multiple ways of dealing with inheritance, two are outlined in the [cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization).

One way involves changing how you check for a role: if you had an `admin?` method, then instead of just checking for the presence of the admin role it would also check for the presence of any other roles that should inherit all of that access.

Another way is to split your ability file into methods named after the role, for example all the statements for the editor role would be in the `editor` method, the `manager` method contains all the statements for the manager role etc. If for example managers need to inherit the access an editor has then call the `editor` method from `manager`.

Comment: many many thanks for this very fast reply! Your suggestion works perfectly! Sorry an upcoming question: 

How is this with inheritance?

"Editor has same permission PLUS some more?

Comment: Outlined two of the approaches you can take.

Comment: @Jan say thanks by accepting this answer. will be easier for others to find this answer too.